# How to generate the object list in observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I have this json

```
"gm" : {
    "handlename1" : {
        "website" : "EOD",
        "mobile" : "1236",
        "prevwalk" : "mj,ann,",
        "createdat" : "datetimehere"
    },
    "handlename2" : {
        "website" : "PPO",
        "mobile" : "1236",
        "prevwalk" : "mj,ann,",
        "createdat" : "datetimehere"
    },
    "handlename3" : {
        "website" : "MTC",
        "mobile" : "1236",
        "prevwalk" : "mj,ann,",
        "createdat" : "datetimehere"
    }
}
```

and passed it to observable array if you check in console log this is the result
[image]

How can I put this in table and display the handlenames?

Please Halp, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rafaeleyng/6fq5q7dw/) with an working example. I warn you: it is not very elegant and concise code, but giving your requirements, it was the only thing I could think of.

Explanation:

Inside the `foreach: handlenamesObs`, in each iteration one object from the `handlenamesObs` array is bound to the `$data` variable.  So, in the first iteration, `$data` will be `'handlename1'`, then `'handlename2'` etc. That does the part where you want to display the handlenames.

Then, when I use the `with: $root.gm[$data]`, I'm saying "ok, in any element that comes inside this current  element, my `$data` object is not the 'handlename1' string, but instead, my object here is `gm['handlename1']`, and inside my `<span>` I want to display the `website` property from this `gm['handlename1']` object.

And the `$root` is used because, if not using it, knockoutjs would look for the `gm[$data]` property inside of `$data` itself. Since `$data` is simply the string `'handlename1'`, there is no meaning in calling `'handlename1'.gm[$data]`. So, instead of calling `gm[$data]` from the implicit `$data` object, we want to call it in the root scope, that is the ViewModel instance itself.

Comment: the json is from the result of firebase. Firebase has very strict contruction in json format.

Answer (score 1):

To make thinks a whole lot easier to just put your table header from within each json object and (which is what ive done) It's not impossible to do it the way you have, just a pain in the ass

Heres my JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sgg8uoy3/11/
And heres the HTML

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr data-bind="foreach: cols">
    <th data-bind="text: header"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-bind="foreach: cols">
    <td>
      <div data-bind="text: website"></div>
      <div data-bind="text: mobile"></div>
      <div data-bind="text: prevwalk"></div>
      <div data-bind="text: createdat"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var vm = (function(jsonData) {

var cols = ko.observableArray(jsonData.gm);
//$.each(jsonData.gm, function(i, item) {
//    cols.push(item);
//});
console.log(cols());

return {
    cols: cols   
} // the following just passes the json in kinda like a get request
})(JSON.parse('{"gm":[{"header":"handlename1","website":"EOD","mobile":"1236","prevwalk":"mj,ann,","createdat":"datetimehere"},{"header":"handlename2","website":"PPO","mobile":"1236","prevwalk":"mj,ann,","createdat":"datetimehere"},{"header":"handlename3","website":"MTC","mobile":"1236","prevwalk":"mj,ann,","createdat":"datetimehere"}]}'));
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

oh btw my json (moved header into each gm object) is:

```
{
   "gm":[
      {
         "header":"handlename1",
         "website":"EOD",
         "mobile":"1236",
         "prevwalk":"mj,ann,",
         "createdat":"datetimehere"
      },
      {
         "header":"handlename2",
         "website":"PPO",
         "mobile":"1236",
         "prevwalk":"mj,ann,",
         "createdat":"datetimehere"
      },
      {
         "header":"handlename3",
         "website":"MTC",
         "mobile":"1236",
         "prevwalk":"mj,ann,",
         "createdat":"datetimehere"
      }
   ]
}
```